# Apache Proxy Tomcat Timeout on 443 port, but ok in another port

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, timeout, proxypass

Someone expert in Apache God level raised to infinity: please help:

I have a Tomcat application server, and to access it I have an Apache as a proxy (mod_proxy, ProxyPass), with SSL operating under port 443.

The issue is that I have an endpoint (Tomcat) that takes about 3 minutes to respond (that is, I don't need to be asked why it takes so long or if you can change that or anything similar, please). The issue is that after 2 minutes the proxy invokes the Tomcat endpoint again, aborting the previous request). I have reviewed timeout settings and everything is fine.

The most curious thing is that it only happens if the HTTPS operates under port 443, if I change it to another port, for example, 70, it works without any problem, that is, it expects the endpoint to end and respond, but if I leave it at 443 The request aborts me.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: What infra do you have between httpd and tomcat?  Firewall?  Other proxy? ...?

Comment: nothing, both services are in the same machine